# Quarkus Qute Include template inside template

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I want to build out a set of templates to help create bootstrap components. This would work fine, except I also use a template for my main page, and thus requires calling templates within templates. Simplified examples below:

Main page template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
...

{#insert pageContent}<h1>No body!</h1>{/}

...
</body>
</html>
```

index.html template (what is injected as page template):

```
{#include webui/mainWebPageTemplate}

{#pageContent}

{! barfs here! !}
{#include webui/bootstrapComponents/modal}
{title}Add/Edit Storage Block{/title}
{/include}

{/pageContent}
{/include}
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is I create a base template, much like your main page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{#insert title}{/}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="modify">{#insert body}No body!{/}</section>
    <footer class="info"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

This acts as the wrapper for your other templates. But I think your issue may be in your index template. instead of using `{#pageContent}` build it out like a regular html page like so:

```html
{#include base}
    {#title}Your title here {/title}
    {#body}
    ...put your content including other templates in here...
    {/body}
{/include}
```

This works for me. Also, the Quarkus site has two good references on the qute engine. [Qute Templating Engine](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute) and the [Qute Reference Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference)